# Huygens formula

Tags: geometry

Let AB - arc of the circle , and  the scale degree  of the arc, and
as the radius of the circle are unknown . For approximate calculation of the length of the arc
used as follows. Notes on the arc of the middle M and measured
chord AB and AM. The approximate value of the length of the arc AB p is computed by Huygens formula  $q=2l+1/3*(2l-L)$  $( l = AM , L = AB)$
Assess the relative error $δ=|q-p|/p$  depending on scale degree of arc AB .
PS. I've try to count relative error but I've got equation what I can't solve .